# How can I POST an array in Swift? (Getting bytes to my server)

Tags: node.js, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to `POST` an array in Swift using Alamofire.

This is my Swift code:

```
        var itemsToSend: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = []

        for i in 0..<selectedSongs.count {
            let app = ["Info" : selected[i]["Info"]!]
            itemsToSend.append(app)
        }

        let toSend = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: itemsToSend, options: [])
        print(toSend) //142 bytes

        let data: [String: Any] = [
            "UID":  FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid as Any as! String,
            "ID": "-",
            "total" : selected.count,
            "sendArray" : toSend
        ]

        let URLString = "http://www.example.com/mult/"

        Alamofire.request(URLString, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
            print(response.result.value)
        })
```

On my server, when I print `sendArray` I get: `142 bytes`. How can I an array in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert it data simply set your array with your key `sendArray`.

```
let data: [String: Any] = [
    "UID":  FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid!,
    "ID": "-",
    "total" : selected.count,
    "sendArray" : itemsToSend
]
```

Comment: Tried that, I get `undefined` when I print on my server.

Comment: @user82395214 Then check that `sendArray` key is the one or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. `console.log(req.body.sendArray)` produces `undefined`.

Comment: @user82395214 Change your encoding to `JSONEncoding.default` from `URLEncoding.default`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Alamofire, you don't need to use `JSONSerialization`, use `JSONEncoding.default` for encoding option when you are sending request

```
let data:[String: Any] = ["foo":"bar", "items":["this", "is", "an", "array"]]

// use JSONEncoding.default instead
Alamofire.request(URLString, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
    print(response.result.value)
})
```

on the server side, you will need to decode the post body using JSON decoder rather than URL decoder